# iPhone post images to Facebook Feed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               photoDescription, @"message",
                               image, @"image",
                               nil];


[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                    andParams:params
                                andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                  andDelegate:self];
```

This is what I did to upload a image to Facebook. The image is uploaded successfully to FaceBook 'photos'. But I want to post the image to my FaceBook Feed. So i tried,

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                                    andParams:params
                                andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                  andDelegate:self];
```

but it still the images posted to the 'photos'. It does not appear in the Feed...

I searched and used different methods for a solution, but I couldn't find anything helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your `params` looks like, but try this..

```
UIImage *image = ...// some image.

NSData *imageData= UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"some message", @"message", imageData,@"source", nil];

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: I believe this is the same as the solution in the question. In other words it will only post to the users time line, not to the news feed.

Comment: Edited my answer to utilize Facebook's dialog method, and not the graph request. Can't test right now, but hopefully that's the answer

Comment: I've just tried out your solution but it didnt post the image to Facebook at all. I thought the `feed` dialog would be correct too. I've also tried `me/feed` which didn't work either.

Comment: To post the user's feed, use the dialog "feed" instead of posting an object. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage* image=...;
if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions
         indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {

        NSArray *permissions =
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream", nil];
        [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {}];
    }
    else
    {
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setObject:@"Photo post test..." forKey:@"message"];
    [params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"picture"];
    //for not allowing multiple hits

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             //showing an alert for failure
             UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:@"Post Failed"
                                       message:error.localizedDescription
                                       delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alertView show];

         }
         else
         {
             //showing an alert for success
             UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:@"Post success"
                                       message:@"Shared the photo successfully"
                                       delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alertView show];

         }
     }];
    }
```